# Powershell: Importing date into Excel changes format

Tags: excel, powershell

I've been using the following code to add a date into excel

```
$worksheet.Cells.Item($current_Row,3) = ([datetime]$entry.Completed_Date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

However when I check in excel, the format is always "MM/dd/yyyy"

Is there anyway to manipulate the string? Or change the cell format so that the date stays in "dd/MM/yyyy"

Edit: My current solution is this
I set the cells format using `.Numberformat = 'dd/MM/yyyy'` and then I need to format the date to be in MM/dd/yyyy. Excel will then flip around the MM and dd for me. It looks like excel is anticipating the date to be inputted in `MM/dd/yyyy` before changing it to `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: what is the cell format in excel set to? i _think_ that is what decides the format. however, if you just want to make a string, you can use `$Date.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')` to get the format you want. it will be a string, tho, not a date object.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey How Do I set the cell format? I tried using `.Numberformat = "dd/MM/yyyy"` but that didn't do anything either. In regards to the `ToString` part, isn't that what I am doing? I have cast the value to `[datetime]` and put it in brackets before using `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") `

Comment: What if you try `.Numberformat = 'dd/MM/yyyy'` (SINGLE quotes) ?

Comment: @Shadowzee - i don't have excel, so i don't know how to do that. [*blush*] ///// i apologize for missing the part where you DID use the `.ToString()` method. if excel is STILL reformatting your entry, then it is _excel_ that is the problem. as mentioned earlier, i simply can't test that.

Comment: @Theo I already tried that but it didn't make a difference

Comment: I think you need to enter the date as `[DateTime]` object instead of using `ToString()` there, so: `$worksheet.Cells.Item($current_Row,3) = ([datetime]$entry.Completed_Date)`. After inserting the date, you change the cell format with `.Numberformat = 'dd/MM/yyyy'`